# Sort Custom Tileset Features in MapBox Studio or GL

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, sorting, mapbox-studio

I have a large number (hundreds of thousands) of point features uploaded to my account in MapBox studio as a dataset, and have generated a tileset based on that dataset.  This tileset is used in a Style as a layer source for a circle layer.  I am then using this style as the basis for a slippy map implemented in MapBox GL JS

**How do I use one of the properties of the features in my datasource to determine the drawing order of the features in mapbox gl**?  I can't see any options for that in the style editor. I've tried setting the circle-sort-order layout property

`map.setLayoutProperty('<layername>','circle-sort-key',["-",["get","<propertytosorton>"]])`

but that did not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are subtracting `undefined` from `propertytosorton`. Not sure about the results.

If you want to sort in ascending order (large values drawn over/after small values) of the property you should:

```json
"layout": {
  "circle-sort-key": ["get", "propertytosorton"]
}
```

If you want to sort in descending order (small values drawn over/after large values):

```json
"layout": {
  "circle-sort-key": ["*", -1, ["get", "propertytosorton"]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is a combination of the question and previous suggestion. Here is the answer I found:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('layername','circle-sort-key',["*", -1, ["get", "propertyname"]])
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708747/mapbox-studio-feature-z-ordering/72739859#72739859